# Is it ever ok to have mapping logic inside a domain primitive?

Tags: domain-driven-design

We have some domain primitives for representing an Account an Amount with Currency etc.
These are in a shared library, so all our microservices can use them.

And then we started adding some convenience methods like Amount.of(String currency, BigDecimal value) and Account.fromIdentifier(String) etc.

These are really convenient methods to have access to, but I think they are kind of breaking the separation between layers. Because now, the domain layer knows what a valid account identifier looks like etc.

How would you design this? I think having a copy of these methods in each app is not really great. And what is the **real benefit** of separating out these, maybe into a different library?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't understanding valid identifiers a core responsibility of the domain layer?

Comment: Please explain in which other layer you would prefer to place the domain knowledge of "what a valid account identifier looks like"  if not in the Domain layer, and why, Tick me after you edited your question, so I can remove my close vote ("needs details or clarity").

Comment: *These are in a shared library, so all our microservices can use them.* This is an architectural smell imo, because this often means the microservices don't align with the bounded contexts. There are exceptions of course, when the library is a **shared kernel** owned by and used in multiple contexts, but even then you have to be mindful that this can easily lead to a distributed monolith.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its ok when the mapping is integral to the type rather than some business logic or helper class that will change over time.

So for example, if you have `currency.Symbol` or `Currency.NewFromSymbol(char symbol)` for £, €, $, etc that seems completely justifiable to me. You will never change those symbols and their mapping because they are part of the definition of what a currency is.

The danger is these methods expand to cover convenience helper methods, say `currencyAmount.ToString(string language); // $1 999,00 or $1,999.00` now you have added a whole new domain of "how to display numbers in different culture formats" to your "how to represent currency in accounts" domain.

Before you know it your domain objects library becomes a massive hodge podge of helper functions which are hard to change because everything consumes them and you don't have visibility on what uses them.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the real benefit of separating out these, maybe into a different library?

That you can version it. Now you can maintain it in one place and be explicit with your dependence on it. That lets each microservice show exactly what it needs.

As for account identifiers, understand, just because some code knows `Account` exists doesn't mean it ever touches identifiers. Sometimes you just want to store amounts. Sometimes you just want to add them up. Sometimes you want to parse them from some string. Doing one doesn't require you to know how to do the other.